# calling another page id in our page?

Tags: javascript

actually i have problem of fetching id of another page div.

i have main index page in which in anchor  tag i passed one function. this fn contain event and another page.
but now in js file when i tried to call that page id using
document.getElementById

it was giving null value.

please help.
thanks

Comment: You cannot use javascripts to fetch IDs from other pages.

Comment: that file is included in main page function then...

Comment: Can you post some (minimalized) example code? HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If `document.getElementById("id")` returns null then the document cannot find an element with that id. *In order to grab an element by its id, it must be part of the dom.*

If you are absolutely positive that it is part of the dom (like you have used the browser's dev tools and found it) then one thing to look out for - a mistake I've made multiple times - is to do `document.getElementById("#id")` - notice the '#' before the id like how you would select it in css or with jquery. If that is present then it won't find the element and return null.